# Sharing data thru WCF services and aspx pages

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, iis-7.5

My web app exposes a few services (WCF) and I need to load an XML file and 'store' it a static variable visible to the entire AppDomain. That variable needs to be queried and updated from either a service or a page.

The thing is, I load that variable in the Application_Start (Global.asax.cs) but when a service request arrives the variable is empty and needs to be 'reloaded', and that happens with every service (3), so I end up with 3 instances of a static variable.

How can I ensure that all my applications are running on the same AppDomain? what am I doing wrong?

VS2008 SP1 on Win7 RTM box

Comment: I see no way to do this. The WCF service will not be in the same AppDomain as the ASP.NET applciation.

Comment: According to the diagram on this page it is possible... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

Comment: I did not know that. What is the structure of your application in IIS? All one application? All same application pool? Maybe add some debugging code that displays the AppDomain in the three services to see if they're in the same AppDomain or not.

Comment: good tip! it's a simple app (one same app with wcf services and pages) and it is running on the same AppDomain according to the script I found on this site http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/164/managing-worker-processes-and-appdomains-in-iis-7-with-wmi/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of research I found the solution. I'll posting the solution here and many links that helped me find it.

WCF services and ASPX pages DO run on the same AppDomain when running side-by-side (default), my problem was that the AppDomain was being recycled because my app was creating a folder below the root folder of my app. When I moved that creation away from the app itself, the AppDomain quited restarting so I always keep my static values.

Here's a list of interesting post I read and helped my find the solution:

- [WCF Services and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)
- [Recycling (AppDomains, not cans)](http://hyperthink.net/blog/recycling-appdomains-not-cans/)
- [Application vs. AppDomain](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2007/09/02/application-vs-appdomain.aspx)
- [Managing Worker Processes and AppDomains in IIS 7.0 with WMI](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/164/managing-worker-processes-and-appdomains-in-iis-7-with-wmi/)
- [Deleting ASP.NET 2.0 Application Sub-Directories Shuts Down the AppDomain](http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2005/12/01/499144.aspx)
- [ASP.NET v2.0 - AppDomain recycles, more common than before](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/02/21/ASP.NET-v2.0-_2D00_-AppDomain-recycles_2C00_-more-common-than-before.aspx#440333)